# Trouble renaming a database in Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

When i am writing  "alter database first_data modify name = first" then it is giving the syntax error as - "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'modify name = first' at line 1".
what should i do??

Answer (score 1):

This is a Microsoft [SQL Server](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip146.html) command; it uses very different syntax from MySQL/MariaDB.

There is no "database rename" command in MySQL, you can either move all individual tables to a fresh database or dump/reimport.

See this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name

Comment: You mean to say that in ubuntu we cannot rename any database or table for this we have to copy the databases.

Comment: How that link is helpful in my problem??

Comment: It tells you how to rename a database in MySQL.

Comment: Thnxx but here the conclusion is that we cannot rename a database in mysql if we are using it in ubuntu but it is possible in microsoft workbench .

Comment: But Microsoft SQL Workbench does not support MySQL in the first place...

Comment: what does this meant??